# document.write check readyState

Tags: javascript, document.write

I have a script that I need to get to the page as fast as possible. It is used on many sites and has not been consistently implemented. Some pages may be loading it after the DOM is ready so I cannot always safely use document.write. Is it safe to check for (document.readyState === 'loading') and if true use document.write else appendChild.

```html
<script>
var js = document.createElement('script');
js.src = 'http://domain.com/script.js';

if (document.readyState === "loading") {
    document.write(js.outerHTML);
} else {
    document.body.appendChild(js);
}
</script>
```

Comment: A suggestion I would give is to look for the `DOMContentLoaded` event ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)). This might be what you are looking for. If this event is fired, use AppendChild. Otherwise, your code should work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is totally right.
I have checked `documen.readyState` documentation on [MDN Document.readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState)
and I think it should work correctly.

Comment: I removed the check for interactive as that will overwrite the DOM. I haven't had any issues with checking for loading but I just wanted some reassurance.